# Computing quaternion in three.js to orient object to target direction and normal

Tags: three.js, quaternions

I have a box object that I am using as an instance mesh in THREE.JS and I'm creating a transformation matrix to move each instance to a different position and orientation. I am currently facing a problem with computing the rotation through a quaternion.

The box's main axis is oriented along the world x-axis (1,0,0) and its normal is oriented along the world z-axis (0,0,1). For each target position I have the desired direction vector for the main axis (let's call it 'dir'), and the desired normal vector. How can I compute the quaternion for this transformation?

What I've done so far orients it along the dir axis, but not sure how to apply another transformation to also orient it along the normal axis.

```
// Vectors before: xAxis, zAxis. Vectors after: dir, normal
const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(xAxis, dir.clone().normalize());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying the suggested solution from dcromley and experimenting a bit more I figured out that what worked was to first compute the quaternion between xAxis and dir. After that I applied the quaternion to the zAxis, and then I computed the quaternion between the rotated zAxis and the normal  vector, and then I got the final quaternion by multiplying the two computed quaternions. Code below:

```
// dir and normal are the two known target vectors that are both normalized
const xAxis = new THRE.Vector3(1,0,0);
const zAxis = new THRE.Vector3(0,0,1);
      
const quaternionX = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternionX.setFromUnitVectors(xAxis, dir);

const zAxisRotated = zAxis.clone();
zAxisRotated.applyQuaternion(quaternionX);

const quaternionZ = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternionZ.setFromUnitVectors(zAxisRotated, normal);

const quaternionFinal = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternionFinal.multiplyQuaternions(quaternionZ, quaternionX);
```

Answer (score 0):

(My take -- haven't implemented this)
So xAxis goes to "Dir" and zAxis goes to "Norm".

```
// Set xAxis and zAxis:
  xAxis = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
  zAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
// Get Qx, the rotation of xAxis to Dir:
  Qx.setFromUnitVectors(xAxis, Dir.clone().normalize());
// That will rotate the zAxis:
  zAxis = zAxis.applyQuaternion(Qx);
// Now get the rotation of this (rotated) zAxis to Norm (see Note below):
  Qz.setFromUnitVectors(zAxis, Norm.clone().normalize());
// And the final quaternion:
  Qfinal.multiplyQuaternions(Qx, Qz);

// Note:  This assumes that Norm is normal to Dir.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it, but it doesn't seem to be giving the expected results. Based on what I've tried so far, I think I first need to compute the Qx, apply the Qx rotation to the zAxis vector, compute the quaternion Qz from the rotated zAxis and the target Norm vector, and finally do the multiplyQuaternions(Qx, Qz).

Comment: You're welcome -- so now I have to implement this to see what my code does.  Thanks.